# Generate all combinations of a list given a condition

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics, python-itertools

I would like to generate all combinations of length n, for a list of k variables. I can do this as follows:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

dataset = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
X = dataset.data
y = dataset.target
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=dataset.feature_names)
features = dataset.feature_names

x = set(['mean radius', 'mean texture'])

for s in itertools.combinations(features, 3):
    if x.issubset(set(s)):
        print s
```

len(features) = 30, thus this will generate 4060 combinations where n=3. When n=10, this is 30,045,015 combinations.

```
len(tuple(itertools.combinations(features, 10)
```

Each of these combinations will then be evaluated based on the conditional statement. However for n>10 this becomes unfeasible.

Instead of generating all combinations, and then filtering by some condition like in this example, *is it possible to generate all combinations given this condition?*

**In other words, generate all combinations where n=3, 4, 5 ... k, given 'mean radius' and 'mean texture' appear in the combination?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just generate the combinations without `'mean radius'` and `'mean texture'` and add those two to every combination, thus largely reducing the number of combinations. This way you don't have to filter, every combination generated will be useful.

```
# remove the fixed features from the pool:
features = set(features) - x 
for s in itertools.combinations(features, n - len(x)):
    s = set(s) & x # add the fixed features to each combination
    print(s)
```

Comment: Yes you're right. I will edit the question, as I was looking for a general solution for all values of n, not just n=3.

Comment: @MarcelKlockman my answer also covers all values of n in the second part. Since you edited your question, I also removed the first part of my answer.